# Cannot jump to newer position in jump list

Tags: windows, vim, jump-list

For some reason, I cannot jump forward with `<C-I>`; gives me the error beep. `<C-O>` works just fine.

I don't see any remapping going on either. Any ideas what might be the problem?

I'm using vim 7.3 on win7

EDIT: I just found out `<C-I>` does the same as `%`! I still can't figure out how to fix it though.

Comment: Is it possible you're at the end of the list?  Or that the next target is invalid (file that isn't there anymore, etc?)

Comment: No, the list has both forward and backward jumps within the same file. It works in ViEmu, but not vim. I thought it might be some windows specific mappings, but I cannot find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why does having `<TAB>` mapped affect `<C-I>`?  The short answer is, "historical reasons", dating from even before the original 'vi'.

The ASCII code for `<TAB>` is 9, same as `<CTRL-I>`.  Since terminals receive their input encoded in ASCII, they can't tell whether that "TAB" signal came from the actual `<TAB>` key, or from the user holding `CTRL` and pressing `I`.  Since Vim was originally written to run on terminals, it can't tell the difference either.

A couple of other pairs of indistinguishable keys are `<C-M>` with `<Return>`, and `<C-[>` with `<Esc>`.

It's possible there's some arcane way to tell the difference between the two (more likely if you're using GVim), but if there is, I don't know it.  As a workaround, you could use `nnoremap <SomeOtherKey> <C-I>` to give `<C-I>`'s original function to some other key.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix for the problem, but I don't know why it works..

I had `<TAB>` mapped to `%`. By removing this, `<C-I>` works as normal.

Any idea why this works...?